# My changes to Homestead.yaml are not reflected in the virtual environment after I vagrant up

Tags: laravel, homestead

I edited the shared folder mapping rules in my Homestead.yaml file (C:\Users\username\.homestead). Then, I entered "vagrant halt" command to shut down vagrant. Then, I entered "vagrant up".

However, the edits that I made to the folder mapping are not reflected in the virtual environment. It's as if my changes were not made at all in the Homestead.yaml file.

How do I make the vagrant virtual environment reflect the changes that I made to the Homestead.yaml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should reload using

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not `vagrant destroy`, there are many things involved. If your vagrant is still running do `vagrant provision`, if it is not do `vagrant up --provision`. If things don't work as expected, check your file mappings for mistakes.

Comment: To add to your answer, here is a definitive guide on homestead.yaml, just have a view to avoid many beginners errors. https://abbasharoon.me/homestead-yaml-explained-a-z/

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `vagrant destroy` instead of `vagrant halt` after updating my `homestead.yaml` file.

Comment: `vagrant halt`. Edit Homestead.yaml then  `vagrant up --provision`